# What images should I be using for Windows on Windows with Docker EE on Windows 2016

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core, server

I have been developing and maintaining some windows on windows Docker containers that run ASP.NET core applications on Windows 2016 (using Docker EE) for some time now.  I was planning on turning over all ongoing updates/maintenance to server administrators, but I have hit a problem. When I started I believe I was using SAC builds, but now none of the SAC (or LTS for that matter) builds pull on Windows 2016, and though I have spent a good deal of time googling, this whole thing seems to be a big cluster.   With docker on Linux, I would just use any LTS distro and apply updates when building the container.  Does Microsoft have a clear plan on doing the same?  It seems like they are missing the point of docker.  I want to run a windows on windows container in windows server 2016, and I want to make sure when I recreate it that I am getting the latest security updates.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-container-images-now-published-to-microsoft-container-registry/

This page talks about the big changes made in Docker images recently and specifically says the following:

> .NET Core images for Nano Server 2016 are still available on Docker Hub and MCR and will not be deleted. You can continue to use them but they are not supported and will not get new updates. If you need to do this and previously used manifest tags, like 1.1-sdk, you can now use the following MCR tags (Docker Hub variants are similar)

Does this mean the new tags listed get updates?  I would assume they would tag it with LTS instead of SAC2016 to better convey the notion that they are continuing to update.

This page seems to be really helpful, but none of the images listed pull on windows server 2016:
https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-net-core-mcr-docker-files-runtime-vs-aspnet-vs-sdk/

This is what I get when I attempt to pull any of the images:

```
1709: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

To clarify, I can currently run all my applications using such images as these:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime        2.2-nanoserver-sac2016   4a3bbafea836        3 months ago        1.27GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk            2.2-nanoserver-sac2016   9773d80bdd64        3 months ago        2.62GB
```

I am looking for clarity on support of these images, or a clearer direction to migrate.

Comment: After rereading that whole microsoft page again, it seems to me that though they don't specifically say it, it sounds like they are saying Windows server 2016 is no longer supported at all.  Can anyone confirm or deny this?  If so, this means I either need to request that we move to a later version of windows server, or ironically move to Linux.

Comment: Just to keep track, Chris's suggestion below doesn't work, and depending on the outcome of our fevered discussion, I may still be looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, for LTS, the image you want to pull is: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1`. Since 2.1 is the LTS release of ASP.NET Core. The underlying server reference doesn't matter, honestly, and all the .NET Core images are multi-arch, so the right underlying images are pulled automatically (linux for linux host, Windows for Windows host, and AMD64, x86, ARM, etc.).

The OS of the image (aside from being the right architecture and platform) is really kind of meaningless. It's mostly a translation layer. Images aren't VMs, the OS is on the host, and that's where your security patches and such apply. As long as your host is patched up, you're good.

**UPDATE**

This has apparently led to some pedantic arguments in the comments, so let me be a little more clear. What I'm talking about here is best described via this [graphic from the Docker site](https://blog.docker.com/2018/08/containers-replacing-virtual-machines/):

[image: Containers vs. Virtual Machines]

Whereas a VM has a copy of the OS on each instance, containers utilize a shared host OS. The OS base image is basically a proxy. It provides the API, but everything at an OS-level happens on the host OS, not in the container.

As such, yes, the OS base image matters *to a certain extent*. You can't target a Linux base image and deploy to Windows Server. You'd have issues targeting Windows Server 2019 and deploying to 2016, as well. However, assuming that the OS base image is remotely compatible with the host OS, then everything above and beyond that is meaningless.

Specifically to the discussion of patches and LTS versions, you don't need to care, because again, what's actually running is components of the host OS, not anything from the image itself. You can actually see this if you open Task Manager on the host OS. You'll see duplicate system-level processes tied to each running container. Even though the container shows running processes as well, it is these host-level processes that are actually doing the work, and therefore, it is only important that *they* are patched and supported. If everything is good on your host, you need not worry about the containers, at least for the OS part of things.

Comment: ```>docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
2.1: Pulling from dotnet/core/aspnet
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries```

Comment: And I would respectfully differ from you on your comment about patches.  Vulnerable code that can be used to gain any sort of foothold is just a stepping stone to full control provided that the right exploits exist.  Containers, VMs, chroot jails might make this hard, but nothing should be viewed as a silver bullet.

Comment: I meant just from the OS level part. In other words, what version the OS layer is targeting doesn't need to be "patched" or updated. Think of it like an API. The *actual* DLLs, drivers, and system services running are coming from the *host* OS, so in a sense, if your host OS is up to date, then so is your image OS.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I have to disagree about your statement that the underlying image OS is meaningless. Try running an image based on server 2019 on a 2016 host (e.g., Azure AppServices, AWS, etc) and you'll get a host/image OS mis-match error and the container won't start. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility

Comment: further context: AWS and (selected) Azure services currently run on ltsc2016 host machines

Comment: @JoshE: You're taking me too literally. First, I'm talking about the OPs concerns of keeping things patched up. It's obviously not completely meaningless. Second, the multi-arch image takes care of that for you, so in terms of just wanting something that runs ASP.NET Core 2.1, it *is* meaningless to the end user.

Comment: No objection re: patching things up. There's probably something I'm missing - I guess I'm trying to figure out why it's 'meaningless' when the end user has to know a) their host OS and b) the base OS of the image they want to run? Unless ah, I see what you meant. From the PoV of the OP they just want to know which is the LTS base image. If you wouldn't mind re-wording your post to clarify a bit I'll happily upvote

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant. The OS image only matters if that's what you're targeting directly. Here the OP just wants the LTS release of the ASP.NET Core runtime, so that is the target. The OS image inconsequential, and intentionally so. It will use whatever is most appropriate for the host

Comment: The OP was specifically worried about matching the patch level of the OS image with the host, which is what I was addressing in my answer. That is in fact completely meaningless, because the OS image is just proxying to the host, anyways. It's not some service in the image that's running for example, but rather that service on the host. So, if the host is patched, your container effectively is as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I don't think this is the appropriate place for this discussion, but unless things in docker for windows changed drastically, you are mistaken.  Code in a container is running on the host OS using libraries inside the container that are fixed up to talk to the HOST OS kernel.  Using an old container with vulnerabilities in the code therein is as bad as not patching the host OS.  Particularly for my application that hosts web APIs reachable from outside.

Comment: @lopass: That actually just furthers my point. The sheer fact that you can have an image like scratch is due to the fact that the host OS is where the action is. If Docker depended on anything actually from the image exclusively, then scratch wouldn't work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Please see this more detailed image from another stack overflow question.  It shows that each container has its own libraries.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/exIhw.png
The scratch image described in the link above works because the go binary is statically compiled and its libc implementation connects directly to docker who mediates connection to the kernel.

Comment: @ChrisPratt and another way to think about this:  If everything happens in the host OS, then there is no point in having docker at all.  Just run everything directly in the host OS.  The win with docker is I can run any stack of binaries and libraries that are compatible with my host OS kernel and I can define the versions for that stack in a Dockerfile. This discussion really should be moved to chat, but I don't use stackoverflow enough to click the link to do it.

Comment: Funnily enough, Stack Overflow should have prompted with a link to move to chat by now, but hasn't. There's entire books on how Docker works, so what I've posted here is intentionally basic. Suffice to say that the two are not mutually exclusive. Everything happens on the host *and* yet Docker still very much has a point. What it does is segregate processes, networking, etc. It's not an OS itself, and containers are *not* VMs: they emphatically do not have OSes either.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3761

I was working around Mar 12 when all the docker pulls stopped working because of the changes MS did.  So I am sure I saw this page before, but on rereading the entire thing again, I see this comment:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016
```

That seems like a reasonable tag name for long term support.  Lo and behold it works.  I am currently theorizing that nanoserver is only for the latest and greatest, and am thinking of opening an issue on github to see if someone will answer that definitively.

I think one of the comments on that page from the github maintainer settles the debate in the Chris Pratt's answer.  I think mis-information floating around about security is dangerous, so I am reposting here to help future souls who stumble on this question:

> Yes, when running with process-isolation, the version must match the Windows kernel version you're running on. Unlike Linux, the Windows kernel does not have a stable API, so container images running on Windows must have libraries that match the kernel on which they will be running to make it work (which is also why those images are a lot bigger than Linux images).

Vulnerable libraries in a docker container DO matter.  You cannot rely on the host OS being up to date to protect you.

## Further Research

Still researching this, so adding my updates for your benefit as I find them:

### Article about Migrating

https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/nano-server-no-longer-supported-for-infrastructure/

TLDR - Move to servercore

### Server 2016 14393 Tags on Docker Hub

The main docker hub nano server page does not list any 14393 tags, but visiting the full tags list at the bottom of the page shows many.  I was able to pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:10.0.14393.1066 and it is only 1GB instead of 14GB for server core